# Set field to random number before sending request in Postman

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

I have a POST request in Postman.

One of the fields in the request is a price for an item.

I don't want to manually change the value and then send the request every time.

I want to generate a random value and then set it for the field. Then send the request.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the form-data field to `{{$randomInt}}` to have a randomly generated integer between 1 and 1000 inserted into the request's field.

`KEY` `VALUE`

`price` `{{$randomInt}}`

Comment: The variable name would be `{{$randomInt}}`